# Making my MongoDB instance modular in my NodeJS/Express server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I've recently discovered the design pattern of making thing modular in Express, and was wondering if I could do that to my MongoDB instance as well (and more importantly, SHOULD I do this?) I'm guessing my code would probably look something like this:

```
//db.js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const client = new MongoClient(url);

module.export= client.connect(function(err, client) {
  assert.equal(null, err);

  return client;
});


//index.js
const express = require('express');
const client = require('./db.js');

const app = express();
const db = client.db(dbName);

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    //use the db variable to perform database operations
});
```

First off, would this even work? Could I treat 'client' like an object and export it like this? And if it did work and I could require 'client' as a module, would I still be able to perform client.close() in my index.js file?

EDIT: I just realized my client.connect should probably return the 'client' if I want to set db to client.db(dbname)

Comment: what `client.connect` returns? it doesn't return client, thats a callback. You need to check what client.connect returns. Where does `url` comes from? Do you plan on connecting to more than one mongo client?

Comment: I think it returns a Promise?

Comment: Its unlikely that a method that accepts callback return a promise. If it returned a promise, what would be the point of the callback? Its two different ways of doing the same thing, that is, handling async code

Comment: Under the documentation, I think it says it returns a Promise if no callback is provided

Comment: you are providing a callback

Comment: AH right yea. Sorry I'm a little slow today